# Which LAN card / module combinations proven to work with Wake on LAN

Tags: networking, wakeonlan

I've got a 12.04 headless server that I've been trying to get to work with wake-on-lan. The card is Marvel 88E8053 using the sky2 module. Although WOL is enabled in BIOS and ethtool shows the card as WOL enabled, it refuses to wake when I send the magic packet. I have verified that the packet is being received OK when the machine is on. The machine does wake OK from a BIOS alarm which suggests it is a network card issue.

I've seen reference to bugs in sky2 that mean WOL fails in recent versions of Ubuntu (and have tried [a module conf file as suggested here](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/bug-647560-squeeze-sky2-wake-lan-broken-asus-p5ld2-motherboard-marvell-88e8053-rev-19-re-patch-tested-working-help-207357901.html) but to no avail)

So I am thinking the best bet is to replace the ethernet card with one that definitely works with WOL in 12.04 - please could you post your card make and model no if you are using it successfully, along with any tweaks you had to make?

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup of /etc/init.d/halt and try out the patch listed at the end of following bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ifupdown/+bug/981461

Do a restart and then a shutdown to try WOL.

It worked for me on my HP Proliant server. Hope it works on yours.

**tip** delete the lines show with  a preceeding - sign and insert the ones with + sign. The lines without any sign are just for reference to locate the correct code.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the suggestion. Can you tell me the exact shutdown command you use? I've just tried applying the patch then using "sudo halt -p" but that didn't work

Comment: I tried sudo poweroff. But normal shotdown, using menu also works for me.

Comment: No, unfortunately this did not work. So I renew my call for people to post cards that work out of the box - _are_ there any?

Comment: Can you also try making rc0 and rc6 entries as described in bug. I had done that as well.